# MySQL remote connection to Linux

Tags: mysql, windows, mysql-workbench

[image]

Do I have to install MySQL on Windows to be able to connect to a MySQL server running on Linux and edit the files from windows ? Because I was installing the Workbench for SQL (I'm using MySQL Workbench Guide, Source: [MySQL  Workbench](http://mysqlworkbench.org/2010/12/mysql-workbench-manage-mysql-on-windows-servers-the-windows-way/)), then allow access to Linux (vps) from my pc, when I tried to install it, I'm stuck in the Windows config settings. Can someone help? (Screenshot provided.)

1 more thing: the program said "installing wmi" then "Could not set up connection: Could not connect to  target machine."

Comment: to be able to connect to a MySQL server running on Linux and edit the files from windows , the remote windows config could not set up connection to target machine I don't get it , I got in with SSH login based management but I cant edit the files inside mysql on my linux

Comment: Normally you need a MySQL client to talk to MySQL, not the full server. But your screenshot implies this a question about getting a particular piece of software to talk to MySQL. What software is that? Is it [MySQL Workbench](https://www.mysql.com/products/workbench/)?

Comment: In future, please update the question with the extra information that you're asked for.  It's been done for you this time.  It's also a courtesy to be careful about capitalization of words (Windows, Linux) that are proper nouns, etc.  And use enough punctuation that isn't commas — full stops (periods) every so often are a good idea.  Thanks, and welcome to Stack Overflow.  (Please read the [About] and [Ask] pages soon, and become familiar with how to create an MCVE ([MCVE]).  That's not immediately critical, but it's a good idea to know about it for the future.)

Comment: @Schwern yes it is mysql workbench, I tried with full server and without. Jonathan Leffler Sorry about that i'm still new at this :)

Answer (score 0):

you can install only workbench in windows without installing mysql server but you need to create a user on linux mysql server, who can then access it from the windows machine:

```
CREATE USER 'newuser'@'IP of the windows machine' IDENTIFIED BY 'password';
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON *.* TO 'newuser'@'IP of the windows machine';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
```

if you want the user to access regardless IP then you can use '%' instead of IP

Comment: Tried this and still not working, could not set up connection to target machine. And yes I did restart the mariadb service. Sreenshot:  https://gyazo.com/c64020338a4bd3892674a3458e2d08f3

Comment: do you have remote access enabled in /etc/mysql/my.cnf ?

Comment: this should be under section [mysqld]

Comment: I have my.cnf file in /etc/my.cnf not in /etc/mysql/my.cnf (I'm using MariaDB on CentOS 7), I moved it myself, and this is the inside of it. https://gyazo.com/c0cd9baf34266766b7c13c93696e8f08

Comment: ok, under [mysqld] try adding the line bind-address=ip address of the win machine and then restart the service

Comment: I did and this is what happened when I tried to restart the MariaDB service. https://gyazo.com/518a19b0f7462a04dab8146f00214b40 and the status https://gyazo.com/a01c24fb533e572918638f258b9ac5ae

Comment: I think we've done most of what it's suggested here: https://mariadb.com/kb/en/mariadb/configuring-mariadb-for-remote-client-access/  but please double check. The added line should be something like"bind-address = 192.168.1.150" also you can try bind-address = 0.0.0.0 to enable all the IPs

Comment: I did it's working, but https://gyazo.com/16e77abc822a79de11767ae89f61fa38 , and still Could not set up connection.

Comment: make sure that the server is allowing TCP connections on port 3306

Comment: I did that way before , and did it again still not working :(

Comment: Wait , is it because of this ? https://gyazo.com/ff232d9dbc83d0ce31d317646fb55c01

Comment: it could well be a network problem, depending on the configuration of the virtual machines. First step, ping from client to server and viceversa and see if you get a reply